# Mouse pointer disappears on primary monitor?

Tags: ati, multiple-monitors, mouse, intel-graphics

I just installed ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS with the AMD frglx driver on my Lenovo E550. I have a dual monitor setup over HDMI.

When running on Intel GPU, my mouse works fine in dual screen. When I switch to AMD, the mouse becomes invisible, but only on my laptop screen. On my second screen I get the regular mouse pointer.

Any hints on how to debug/tackle this issue?

[EDIT]

When I boot without my secondary monitor attached, I get a regular mouse pointer on my laptop screen. When I then plug in my HDMI cable, the mouse pointer works fine on both screens.

Answer (score 1):

Combine these commands

```
gksudo modprobe -r psmouse && gksudo modprobe psmouse
```

Let me know if it helped.

Modprobe is used to load or remove kernel modules, for more information see [the manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/karmic/en/man8/modprobe.8.html).

Comment: A good start would be to start using man pages. Man is for manual in terminal. So if you put command as man mount in terminal, it will show you usage of mount command. Modprobe command is used to add or remove modules from kernel. psmouse is the mouse module. Actually, you might require to use both the commands, one after other, as I want to reload the module.

Comment: Well, I thought you didn't understand, that's why I explained in command. Who is the OP by the way you mentioned in your first comment?

Comment: it's okay, main point is, did it work?

Comment: I can't say, you will have to wait for the OP to respond

Comment: I am having the exact same issue running Ubuntu Gnome 15.04.  I tried these commands, but the result was that the issue switched monitors. Now my laptop screen is showing a cursor, whereas the additional monitor is not.

Comment: Sorrt for the wait. It did not help. The mouse still *functions* on my first monitor (click etc. works.) only the pointer has disappeared.