# Mouse pointer Disappears

Tags: mouse

Mouse keeps disappearing and only a reboot resolves the issue.
I have attempted the numerous fixes found online and here ([Mouse pointer disappears on primary monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671616/mouse-pointer-disappears-on-primary-monitor)) with no success.

Version 20.04.2

Answer (score 0):

I am on POP OS now, before ubuntu 20.04 on old Imac (always trouble with graphics driver). I have tried all known solutions but only thing that has helped me is switch to another desktop environment, in my case Mate.